# Python3 : dict sort 2nd level by 3rd level values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nested

I have been fighting for hours on this problem. I have the following simplified dict

```
dico = {
    "posts": {
        "k1": {"val": 2},
        "k2": {"val": 1},
        "k3": {"val": 3},
        "k4": {"val": 0},
        }
}
```

that I want to be sorted at the 2nd key level (k1, k2...), by the value of the 3rd level "val" key.
The result I need is the following :

```
dico = {
    "posts": {
        "k4": {"val": 0},
        "k2": {"val": 1},
        "k1": {"val": 2},
        "k3": {"val": 3},
        }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with `sorted` ?
I could not achieve to go further than `sorted(dico['posts'], key=lambda x: dico['posts'][x]['val'])` which gives:

```
['k4', 'k2', 'k1', 'k3']
```

Infinite thanks in advance for your help !!

Comment: The base type `dict` is not sorted, *by definition*.  If you want a sorted dict, you have to switch to one of the derivatives that supports order, such as collections.DefaultDict.

Comment: @Prune Python 3.7's dicts keep their insertion order, and I think it has been out long enough by now so we can assume OP is using that or newer

Comment: Ah -- I've been running into far too many 2.7 posts this week.  Good point -- yes, dicts now retain their order.
In this case, I'm wondering where OP is stuck -- the sort order is properly determined, now it's merely insertion.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using 3.7.3

Comment: @Prune collections.DefaultDict doesn't exist.

Comment: My mistake: it's lower-case: **defaultdict**

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming CPython >= 3.7 is used**

`sorted` can only ever return a list, so if you want to be able to still access the inner dict (in order to reassign them in a sorted manner) you need to sort `dico['posted'].items()`, otherwise it will only sort the keys.

```
dico['posts'] = dict(sorted(dico['posts'].items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['val']))
```

Now since we sort  `dico['posts'].items()`, `sorted` returns a sorted list of tuples (try to print it) so we just convert it back to `dict` and assign it back.

```
dico = {
    "posts": {
        "k1": {"val": 2},
        "k2": {"val": 1},
        "k3": {"val": 3},
        "k4": {"val": 0},
        }
}

dico['posts'] = dict(sorted(dico['posts'].items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['val']))
print(dico)
```

outputs

```
{
    "posts": {
        "k4": {"val": 0},
        "k2": {"val": 1},
        "k1": {"val": 2},
        "k3": {"val": 3},
    }
}
```

Comment: Briliant, that works flawlessly, thank you so much !